# Prevent dragging of cell to the left in iOS7 tableview editing mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

Screenshot below shows one tableview cell in editing mode after swiping to the left on the row. While in editing mode I can hold the cell and drag further to the left again which reveals this white space (bouncy effect when I let go). I'm setting each cell's background image as follows:

cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CellBG.jpg"]];

I have 2 questions.

1. Is it possible to prevent this extra dragging so this white area will never be seen? Would like the same behaviour as the iOS7 weather app for example.
2. Also, any idea why there is thin white line under the delete button?

Thanks

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is it possible to prevent this extra dragging so this white area
>      will never be seen?

Yes. Put the image on the `UITableView`'s background. Not on the cell. Because if you put the image background on a cell and when you horizontally swap a cell to delete, that cell will move. That is to say the image background will also move. But if you put it on the `UITableView`, it will not move with the swap. Remember to set `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell`'s background color to be clear color.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ReuseIdentifier"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBackground.png"]];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, kCellHeight*indexPath.row, 320, cell.frame.size.height);
    [tableView addSubview:imageView];
    [tableView sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
    return cell;
}
```

> 2.Also, any idea why there is thin white line under the delete button?

I think that is Apple's little bug. As you can also find it in the weather app. So never mind that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My tableview will actually need each cell to have a different background image based on user input when creating data for the tableview. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Tim You can do that by applying different background image on different cell. Try my code. It will work.

Comment: As a bonus even the white line is gone :)

Comment: Only issue now is when I delete a row. The tableview background obviously needs to be updated. I've tried doing this by removing all subviews using isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]. The table reloads and the correct images are then added to the background but the background goes black for a second while this is done. Do you know of cleaner way to do this?

Comment: @Tim Hmmm, my way would be to assign each image background an unique tag(bigger than 0) and when you delete one row, go through all the `tableVkew`'s subview and check tag. If tag is not 0, then move it up by the height of the deleted row. Remember to use animation for the move step.